# Show top posts in a proper way Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my posts_controller to display most viewed posts.

```
  def top
    @posts = Post.all.order("post.views DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
```

In routes I have

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      get :top
    end
  end
```

The problem is: when i go to /posts/top i have an error: `Missing template posts/top, application/top` Do I need to write view files for my every method (top isn't the only one) or I can somehow display them in my index file without duplication of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just render the `index` template at the end of your method:

```
def top
  @posts = Post.all.order("post.views DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  render :index
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a close look to rails [layouts and rendering documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). You will get your answer as well concept behind them. Below is the snippet of doc.

In most cases, the ActionController::Base#render method does the heavy lifting of rendering your application's content for use by a browser. There are a variety of ways to customize the behavior of render. **You can render the default view for a Rails template, or a specific template, or a file, or inline code, or nothing at all**. You can render text, JSON, or XML. You can specify the content type or HTTP status of the rendered response as well.